# Using REST API to deploy Liberty Docker containers

Tags: docker, websphere-liberty

Has anyone been able to use the WebSphere Liberty REST API to deploy remote Docker containers? The [docs describe all the steps](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_deployservice_docker.html), but I am not able to repeat the results. I get an error when calling REST deploy function (details are [posted on the other forum](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/286178/nullpointerexception-when-using-rest-to-deploy-rem/)).

If anyone was able to do it - please let me know and would be great if you share how you were able to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not long after posting this question I tried using the curl command with the JSON header spec and now it works. Here is the curl command I am using that works:

```
curl --verbose --insecure -X POST --data @docker_deploy.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" -u ${ADMIN_USER}:${ADMIN_PASSWORD} https://${CONTROLLER_HOST_NAME}:${CONTROLLER_PORT}/ibm/api/collective/v1/deployment/deploy
```